# Comparing arrays to check for sequences

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, comparison

Say we had the following set of nested arrays:

```
var array = [
              [a,b,c],
                  [c,d,e],
                      [e,f,g],
                          [g,h,i]
            ]
```

If we started with `[a,b,c]` and wanted to find any nested array that starts with `c` and, if there are any, push the element at index `2` of that array to a new array which already holds `c`, we could write the following code:

```
var container = [];
container.push(array[0][2]);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[0][2] === array[i][0]) container.push(array[i][2])
```

`container` would therefore end up being `[c,e]`.

Simple enough.

But what if we now also want to check whether or not `e` matches any other `array[i][0]`? And then so on and so forth until we have checked the entire `array` and end up with the following array: `[c,e,g,i]`.

What I'm trying to do is see if the last element of any given array matches the first element of any other array; and, if it does, collect the last element in that array, and also check to see if that element matches the first element of any other nested arrays.

So if we started with `i` we would end up with `[i]`.

If we started with the element `g` we would end up with `[g,i]`.

Right now I'm using nested `for` loops and `if/else` statements like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (element === array[i][0]) {
    container.push(array[i][2]);
    for (var ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++) {
      if (array[i][2] === array[ii][0]) {
        container.push(array[ii][2]);
        for (var iii = 0; iii < array.length; iii++) {
          if (array[ii][2] === array[iii][0]) {
            container.push(array[iii][2])
            for (var iiii = 0; iiii < array.length; iiii++) {
              if (array[iii][2] === array[iiii][0]) {
                container.push(array[iiii][2])
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there not a more efficient way to achieve this?

**I should've mentioned that the initial set of arrays can contain duplicate values like such: `[ [a,b,c], [a,b,c], [g,h,i], [x,y,z] ]` or `[ [a,b,c], [a,b,c], [c,d,e], [x,y,z] ]`.**

To boot I've noticed that my current approach will spit out undesired results such as `[c,e,c,e]` in the second case above instead of simply `[c,e]`.

It might be easier to think about this by using numbers instead:

```
var array = [
              [2,n,4],
                  [4,n,6],
                      [6,n,8],
                          [8,n,10]
            ]
```

If the starting value was `4`, I would then push `array[1][2]` or `6` to `container`, and then try to match `array[1][2]` or `6` to `array[i][0]`. So container would always end up being sequences like `2,4,6,8` or `6,8` or `4,6,8`, etc.

Comment: oh dear god what fresh hell is this

Comment: are the `[a,b,c],[c,d,e]` etc arrays guaranteed to be in some sort of order, or could they be `[c,d,e],[a,b,c]` - in that case what would the expected result be?

Comment: Create an index separately: a map from a letter to a letter.

Comment: `for in` loops could clean it up a bit. I can't think of a way around the if-statements, have you looked in to `array.map`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah, i had no idea how to phrase this question. never had to ask a question like this before lol

Comment: The question isn't bad. I just scrolled down to a quadruple-nested for loop and thought about maybe the two or three times I ever had to do something like that.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, the set of arrays could be in any order. For instance, `[ [a,b,c] [g,h,i] [e,f,g] [c,d,e] ]` and the expected result would be the same; for `c` the result should be `[c,e,g,i]` and the result for `e` should be `[e,g,i]`

Comment: to top it off, i've noticed an issue with my approach. i'll adjust the question above

Comment: ok, so you always look for a corresponding first value for a given value, and build up the result "backwards" - what are the chances of "loops" or multiple identical values in the first/last position?

Comment: @JaromandaX it is indeed possible that i'll end up with an array with identical values like so: `[ [a,b,c], [c,d,e], [c,d,e], [g,h,i] ]` or even  `[a,b,c], [a,b,c], [c,d,e], [c,d,e]` in which cases the result i'm looking for would be, if `c` was the starting value for both, `[c,e,i]` and `[c,e]` respectively. sorry if that wasn't clear in my initial question. duplicate values is why i believe my current approach is running into issues and giving out values `[c,e,c,e]`

Comment: @Anthony I believe he meant like `[a,b,c],[c,d,e],[e,c,a]`. If you started with `a`, your current approach would also never end. What would the expected output for this one be?

Comment: @zerkms can you elaborate? i'm aware of the `map` method but i'm not sure what you mean by mapping from a letter to a letter. in my question those are just placeholders for elements

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ohhhh okay yeah duplicate values like that aren't at all possible

Comment: @Anthony is it possible to have two inner arrays that have the same start value and two different end values? How do you deal with those?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Nope! Any given start value will always have an immutable corresponding end value. Think of it like this: `[ [2,0,4], [4,0,6], [8,0,10], [14,0,16] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this is what [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512103/comparing-arrays-to-check-for-sequences#comment76016911_44512103) meant by creating a separate index which is a map of letter-to-letter:

```js
var stringArray = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['g', 'h', 'i']
];
var numberArray = [
  [2, 3, 4],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [8, 9, 10]
];

// this implementation assumes there are no cycles or divergent branches
function chainSearch(array, start) {
  var container = [start];
  var map = new Map();
  var index, inner, first, last;
  var current = start;
  
  // construct an element-to-element map in O(N)
  for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    inner = array[index];
    first = inner[0];
    last  = inner[inner.length - 1];
    
    if (!map.has(first)) {
      map.set(first, last);
    }
  }
  
  // assuming the chain is length L
  // whole implementation is ~O(N+L) instead of O(N^L)
  while (map.has(current)) {
    current = map.get(current);
    container.push(current);
  }
  
  return container;
}

console.log(chainSearch(stringArray, 'c').join());
console.log(chainSearch(stringArray, 'g').join());

console.log(chainSearch(numberArray, 2).join());
console.log(chainSearch(numberArray, 6).join());
```

The nice thing about this implementation is that, even though the demo uses primitives (strings and numbers), this works for nested arrays of non-primitives as well, assuming that you're testing for references to the same objects rather than identical copies.

Comment: i'm probably going to have to play around with this and sit with it to really understand it. does `new Map()` create some sort of prototype object? i know that the `map()` method accepts 3 parameters/arguments, but it doesn't seem like that's what you're using here? i've never seen `map.has` (reminds me of `hasOwnProperty`), `map.set`, or `map.get` before.

Comment: @Anthony [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) has _nothing_ to do with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It's essentially a hash table.

Comment: Okay, first time hearing about this. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is what you're talking about right?

Comment: i'm gon try embedding that and if it works i'll mark this as the solution. thanks for introducing me to this new object thing :)

Comment: what exactly does `.join()` method do? can't find any info about it on mdn

Comment: @Anthony `container` is an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It's just [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). I did that so the output would display nicely, that's all.

Comment: also, one last thing: what exactly did you mean in your comment by 'no divergent branches'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146478/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-anthony).

Comment: hey pat, when u get a chance would u mind looking at our private chat and letting me know if that's possible to do with Map()? thanks<33

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this approach :

```
function seq(source, result) {
        if (source.length === 1) 
            return result.concat(source[0][source[0].length - 1]);                        

        result = result || [];

        if (source[0][source[0].length - 1] === source[1][0]) 
             result = result.concat(source[1][0]);

        return seq(source.slice(1), result);
    }

    console.log(seq(array));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (in_array(array[i][0], container)) { //if first element of current array matches any element in container
    //add it to container if it's not already there
    if (!in_array(array[i][2], container)) {
      container.push(array[i][2]);
    }
    //and then recheck all arrays to see if they match the new element
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: hm... what's the JS equivalent of that PHP function?

Comment: notably, i think you misunderstood my question. i'm not comparing `array` to `container` but rather comparing `array[a][2]` to `array[z][0]` and if `array[a][2] === array[z][0]` then i add `array[a][2]` and `array[z][2]` to the `container` array, and then compare `array[z][2]` to `array[_][0]` for more matches

Answer (score -2):

for each array, see if any other array starts with the this arrays last value, before or after

```
var container = [];
for (var i=0; i < ary.length; i++) 
   for (var j=0; j < ary.length; j++) 
       if (i != j && ary[i][2] == ary[j][0])
           container.push(ary[j][0]);
```

If you are only looking at later sub arrays then simply start the inner loop at the next index

```
var container = [];
for (var i=0; i < ary.length; i++) 
   for (var j=i+1; j < ary.length; j++) 
       if (i != j && ary[i][2] == ary[j][0])
           container.push(ary[j][0]);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He only wants to include arrays that match other arrays that have already matched the original array.

Comment: i had tried something like the top example already, but the issue with that approach is that if i find a match i then also need to compare the match to the rest of the array; in other words, if `array[0][2]` or `c` matches `array[1][0]` or `c` i then need to compare `array[1][2]` or `e` to the rest of the arrays. does that make sense?

Comment: yes, its an outer an inner loop so it will compare every array against every array.    len * len amount of comparisons.     If you are only looking for the first match, then you could simple break out of the inner loop after you add it to the container {  container.push(); break; }

Comment: don't downvote responses if you are unable to describe the problem set of your homework assignment

Comment: @Steve i haven't down voted a single thing on this thread... but i do believe you're misunderstanding my question/scenario nonetheless